# How does Dalvik/JVM handle multi processed apps

Tags: java, android, jvm, multiprocessing, dalvik

I'm wondering if **Dalvik** instance is being forked per application or per process, that's to say if I've got an app with multiple processes do I also have multiple Dalvik instances? And how does actually multi processing happen?

Let me describe a simple scenario:

I start an app which starts an activity which runs in the first process, then I click a button which spawns another activity which starts to run in a different process.

So when I click a button is another instance of Dalvik being forked, and  is the byte code being interpreted with the newly instantiated Dalvik? And if its true, how does the process switching happen. Say if I go back to the first activity how does the runtime determine that now the first Dalvik should interpret the byte code?

Comment: "if I've got an app with multiple processes do also have multiple Dalvik instances?" -- yes. "I want a very detailed answer..." -- what you want is well beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. Buy a book on [Android internals](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do).

Comment: With the edit your question falls into the "recommending something" closing category, which will not help you get the question reopen. Please be specific as possible with your question.

Comment: (After more edits...) The Linux kernel takes care of execution scheduling and other process management. A single instance of the Dalvik VM does not span processes.

Comment: so the Dalvik instance is one for an app

Comment: No, the Dalvik instance is one for a process.

Answer (score 0):

Activities are not processes. A single process / app can have many [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) instances, each of which are essentially just Java objects. Clicking a button that launches a new activity is therefore more analogous to creating a new instance than launching a new process.

Process switching, when it does occur, is handled at the OS level just like any other Unix-based OS. Processes are running concurrently and are given more or less time on the processor as the OS sees fit.

It might be helpful to go through the [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) and [Best Practices for Background Jobs](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html) training, which will give you more background.